# How to use NSRange or NSScanner in iOS

Tags: iphone, regex, nsstring, nsattributedstring, nsregularexpression

I have a string like:

`1 this is my first text 2 his is my second 3 this is my third 4 this is my forth etc etc..`

Each sentence is between the numeric `characters like 1 2 3 4 etc`

When I tap the first sentence, it needs to dissect it and copy it in clipboard or something. How can we use he NSScanner or NSRange to calculate the string size or identify strings between the numeric characters.

self.multiPageView.text =combined;  the combined contains the text like above ,,so when i tap the first sentence it need to select and show a UIAlertView which conforms the tapped sentence is first sentence,how to dectected a sentence between numeric characters by tap pin that sentence,like ibook. I am using core text to show these type of text.

Comment: I would like to comment that it would be helpful for getting better support from the SO community, that you have a look at the Markdown syntax which is used by SO to format your questions appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `NSScanner` Like -

```
NSString *yourString = @"1 this is my first text 2 his is my second 3 this is my third 4 this is my forth";

NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:yourString];

[scanner scanUpToString:@"1" intoString:nil];
if (![scanner isAtEnd]) {
    [scanner scanUpToString:@"1" intoString:nil];
    NSCharacterSet *charset = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"2"];
    [scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:charset intoString:&yourString];
}
```

Comment: i have a doubt,i am rendering thiese text through coretextr,so how can  detect that i touched the first sentence or second sentence.is there any way to highlight or popup a alert view which incudes a message that this is first sentence .?

Comment: you need to reframe question with your actual issue, and what you are trying to achieve

Comment: so is it not possible to know which sentence is tapped?

Comment: i won't said that, you need to define your requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Try this you will get array in which there will be all seperated strings. You have to fill set with numbers you are using.

```
    NSString *str1 = @"1 this is my first text 2 his is my second 3 this is my third 4 this is my forth";
    NSMutableCharacterSet *set = [NSMutableCharacterSet controlCharacterSet];
    [set addCharactersInString:@"1"];
    [set addCharactersInString:@"2"];
    [set addCharactersInString:@"3"];
    [set addCharactersInString:@"4"];
    NSArray *arr = [str1 componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:set];
```

Comment: haii,1 2 3 4 is dynamic,so how can i write this code?the actual code is  self.multiPageView.text =combined; companied contains these texts.combined is dynamic.