# Extract text from some parsed NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, nsstring, nsregularexpression

This is my example string, parsed from a remote server:

```
NSString *example = @"#parsed Value1:1a 2013-02-20 10:00:00 UTC Value2=2a Value3=3a Value4=4aKm Value5=A"
```

I need to extrapolate the single ValueS from the above string, separated, without other characters:

```
"1a"
"2013-02-20 10:00:00 UTC"
"2a"
"3a"
"4a"
"A"
```

Please suggest me the right code to do that (I've tried without success with regex), thank you!

Comment: example string format remain same or it will change?

Comment: I think you have some mistakes in the example like using ':' instead of '=', or not writing the 'ValueX=' for the second parameter, please, correct them before...

Comment: Im sorry @apascua, but it's correct: "Value1" has ':' and other values have '='

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the format will stay the same, you don't need to use a regex.

Try using `NSScanner`, particularly the methods `scanUpToString:intoString:` and `scanString:intoString:`

EDIT:

This code should be what you need:

```
NSString *example = @"#parsed Value1:1a 2013-02-20 10:00:00 UTC Value2=2a Value3=3a Value4=4aKm Value5=A";

NSString *temp, *value1, *date, *value2, *value3, *value4, *value5;
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:example];
// By default, NSScanner will skip whitespace - we don't want it to skip anything here
[scanner setCharactersToBeSkipped:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@""]];
[scanner scanString:@"#parsed Value1:" intoString:&temp];
[scanner scanUpToString:@" " intoString:&value1];
[scanner scanString:@" " intoString:&temp];
[scanner scanUpToString:@" Value2=" intoString:&date];
[scanner scanString:@" Value2=" intoString:&temp];
[scanner scanUpToString:@" Value3=" intoString:&value2];
[scanner scanString:@" Value3=" intoString:&temp];
[scanner scanUpToString:@" Value4=" intoString:&value3];
[scanner scanString:@" Value4=" intoString:&temp];
[scanner scanUpToString:@" Value5=" intoString:&value4];
[scanner scanString:@" Value5=" intoString:&temp];
value5 = [example substringFromIndex:[scanner scanLocation]];
```

Comment: You're welcome. BTW it's not "the right code", it's just my take on a solution to the problem. There's always more than one way to skin a cat!

Answer (score 1):

The regex for those exact key names is something like:

```
#parsed Value1:(.*) (.*) Value2=(.*) Value3=(.*) Value4=(.*) Value5=(.*)
```

If the list is variable length, you can group inside of `()?`If you need arbitrary keys, you'll need to group and repeat something that can detect the `key=value` pattern.

Comment: I'd change your regex and use non greedy quantifiers, just in case.... Replace `(.*)` with `(.*?)`

Comment: Thank you, @Peter, please can you provide some code to do that? Im very beginner at that!

Answer (score -1):

You can also use NSScanner see the [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10663014/how-to-use-nsrange-or-nsscanner-in-ios) and [link2](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html)